# How do you perform Bulk Edits in TFS for Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

How do you perform Bulk Edits in TFS for Visual Studio 2013?

For example, I've created several Product Backlog Items and I want to move 40 of them to a different Area in my project.  So I need to edit the Area Path for 40 of these backlog items.

How is the fastest way to accomplish this, without opening, editing, and closing each of the 40 backlog items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Visual Studio 2013, the following answer applies to that version.

I figured out a REALLY easy way to bulk edit fields for TFS Product Backlog Items:

1. Open the product backlog in Visual Studio/Team Explorer Tab.
2. Highlight all items that you want to change.
3. Click the ‘Open in Microsoft Office’ dropdown and select ‘Open In Microsoft Excel’.
4. Edit the fields you are interested in using standard Excel functionality to copy/paste or replace.
5. Click the ‘Publish’ button at the upper left in Excel.
6. After that has completed, click on the Refresh icon at the top of your product backlog view in Visual Studio.
7. Your updated/bulk-edited entries will now appear.